# How can i open pdf from sdcard i can from asset folder

Tags: android, pdf, android-sdcard

i am using pdf viewer library and able to show pdf from asset folder but while i    am trying to do this from sdcard its just showing progrss bar for long time.

i am using below code for showing from Asset

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "sample.pdf");
    try {
        in = assetManager.open("sample.pdf");
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPdfViewerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, getFilesDir() + "/sample.pdf");
    startActivity(intent);

}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}}
```

And i am using below code for showing from Sdcard

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPdfViewerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME,
            "mnt/sdcard/sample.pdf");

/*  intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME,
            "assets/sample.pdf");*/

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access your PDF file from the SDCard like this:

```
File myPdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"sample.pdf");
String path = myPdfFile.getAbsolutePath();

//Open the Pdf with this Method            
openPdfFileWithFilePath(path);

protected void openPdfFileWithFilePath(String path) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPdfViewerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME,path);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response i didnt try your code becoes my above code works fine. i am getting issues becoes i was working on imulator but when i try it on actual device its work fine . but still having issues . it doesnt show words properly in zoom in znd zoom out

Comment: but still having zoom in issue when i click zoom it disapper some part of pdf can u pls help me to get out from this

Comment: @shivpaljodha look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456928/how-to-create-recyclerview-adapter-in-android?noredirect=1#comment48995142_30456928)dude