# How to create Recyclerview adapter in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using this [LIB](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager). It's working fine but I can not loading my data in adapter class. like.
If i add some static data that will be added but whenever i tries to load from server that will not be added. finally i am trying with this approach.
But when i calls the Brandinfo and try to add data that will be error saying colon missing etc. please tell me how i can i add data to adapter to complete this recyclerview. 
Thanks.
My Fragment class is

```
List<BrandInfo> mContentItems = new ArrayList<BrandInfo>();
pbDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pbDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pbDialog.show();
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("BrandViewActivity", response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            brandInfo = new BrandInfo();
                            mContentItems.add(new BrandInfo().setBrandname(obj.getString("title")));
                            String title = obj.getString("title");
                            String location = obj.getString("location");
                            String image = obj.getString("image_path");
                            String category = obj.getString("category");

                            Log.d("fffffffffff", mContentItems.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error aa gai bhaya", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
```

This is my Brandinfo class:

```
public class BrandInfo {
private String brandname;
private String brandinfo;
private String address;
private String detail;

public String getBrandname() {
    return brandname;
}
public void setBrandname(String brandname) {
    this.brandname = brandname;
}
public String getBrandInfo() {
    return brandinfo;
}
public void setBrandinfo(String brandinfo) {
    this.brandname = brandinfo;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}
public void setSex(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}
```

}

finally this is my adapter class:

```
public class TOAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TOAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<BrandInfo> brandLists = new ArrayList<BrandInfo>();
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public TOAdapter(List<BrandInfo> brandLists) {
    this.brandLists = brandLists;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public TOAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_big, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    // - get data from your itemsData at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

    BrandInfo brandList = new BrandInfo();



   imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(brandList.getBrandname());
    //viewHolder.thumbNail.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    viewHolder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(brandList.getBrandname(), imageLoader);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    String s = String.valueOf(brandLists.size());
    Toast.makeText(AppController.getInstance(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return brandLists.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    final NetworkImageView thumbNail;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.brandtitle);

        thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post where you create the adapter and recyclerview and where you add the new data. Are you sure the response from volley is not null?

Comment: `TOAdapter mAdapter = new TOAdapter(mContentItems);
        RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter mAdapterMaterial = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(mAdapter);


        // 4. set adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterMaterial);
        // 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), recyclerView, null);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());` this is where creating adapter

Comment: and the response is not null. please check here ` for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i); brandInfo = new BrandInfo();  String title = obj.getString("title"); String location = obj.getString("location");String image = obj.getString("image_path");String category = obj.getString("category");Log.d("fffffffffff", mContentItems.toString()); } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }`  please tell me how can i add data,

Comment: Okay where do you update the recyclerview with new data?

Comment: @Smashing tell me how can i add in mCotentItems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29052640/1576416

Answer (score 0):

So what I would recommend is the following (which I use in my own project):

Create the following method in you TOAdapter:

```
public void refreshRecyclerViewBrands(List<BrandInfo> brandLists) {
    this.brandLists = brandLists;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then call the following method from where you initialized the recyclerviewadapter and your list:

```
mAdapter.refreshRecyclerViewBrands(mContentItems);
```

This basically takes the list you just got from volley and tells the recyclerview to use this new list and refresh the recyclerview. This worked for me so hopefully will work for you.

Another thing I noticed is in your `onBindViewHolder` your are setting the following:

```
BrandInfo brandList = new BrandInfo();
```

Then you use:

```
viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(brandList.getBrandname());
```

But brandlist.getBrandname is null.
Never are you actually giving the brandlist object any values, rather use the following :

```
final BrandInfo brandList = brandLists.get(position);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but first tell me the way of adding data in mContentItems?

Comment: So you want to add data on your existing data?

Comment: not on existing data, as you can see i am taking data from server but there is not any code that can add that data in `mContentItems` so i just need how can i add the received data in `mContentItems` so i can access in my adapter class.

Comment: This code should work, assuming mContentItems has your values from the server, use the above code and then use mAdapter.refreshRecyclerViewBrands(mContentItems); This updates the adapter with the new items from the server. Are you struggeling with refreshing your recyclerview or with populating the mContentItems list??

Comment: yes it is working but see i told you about how can i add item according to Brandinfo class. like setBrandName, setImageUrl etc, so my question is how can i set the data i am receiving in the Fragmentclass. see where i am getting data. and please help me in that. will be appreciated.

Comment: `JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                brandInfo = new BrandInfo ();
                                brandInfo.setBrandname(obj.getString("title"));`  but when i toast  `@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        String s = String.valueOf(brandLists.size());
        Toast.makeText(AppController.getInstance(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return brandLists.size();
    }` this in adapter it is always zero.

Comment: Ahhhh so your are struggling with parsing the json response into your object.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401094/parse-android-volley-jsonarray-response

Comment: nooooo dear @Smashing i am getting whole data, please try to understand i am not able to add data in mContentItems. please notice carefully i want to add the received data in mContentItems. so that i can access in my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
  JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
  brandInfo = new BrandInfo();
  mContentItems.add(new                      
  BrandInfo(obj.getString("title"),
   obj.getString("title");
   obj.getString("location");
   obj.getString("image_path");
   obj.getString("category");
```

then i add my adapter like this
        CustomSourcingAdapter adapter=new
        CustomSourcingAdapter(Sourcing_modes.this, publishPlacementList);
        lists.setAdapter(adapter);

```
this is my custom Adapter class
    public class CustomSourcingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SourcingModel> {

private final Activity context;

private final List<SourcingModel> publishPlacementList;

public CustomSourcingAdapter(Activity context,List<SourcingModel>       
publishPlacementList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    super(context, R.layout.sorsinglist,publishPlacementList);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    this.publishPlacementList=publishPlacementList;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView placementtitle;
    protected TextView Noofposition;
    protected ImageButton next;
    protected TextView Department;

}

public View getView(int position,View converview,ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (converview ==null ){
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        converview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sorsinglist, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();




        converview.setTag(viewHolder);
        converview.setTag(R.id.idplacetitle,viewHolder.placementtitle);
        converview.setTag(R.id.idnoofpos,viewHolder.Noofposition);
        converview.setTag(R.id.imreqserch,viewHolder.next);
        converview.setTag(R.id.iddepartment,viewHolder.Department);
    }else{
        viewHolder= (ViewHolder)converview.getTag();
    }
```

viewHolder.placementtitle.setText(publishPlacementList.get(position).getPositionName());
        viewHolder.Noofposition.setText(publishPlacementList.get(position).getNoOfPosition());
        viewHolder.Department.setText(publishPlacementList.get(position).getName());

```
    viewHolder.next.setTag(position);

       viewHolder.next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
            long  id = publishPlacementList.get(pos).getId();

            Intent it = new Intent(context, SourcingSecond.class);
            it.putExtra("id", id);
            context.startActivity(it);

        }
    });


    return converview;

};
```

Comment: its an working code i just remove findview by id methods

Comment: write these lines before oncreat

Comment: ListView lists;
  ArrayAdapter<SourcingModel> adapter;
  List<SourcingModel>publishPlacementList = new ArrayList<SourcingModel>();

Comment: there is no use of arrayadapter.